# How do I install GNU Global with universal ctags support using Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, ctags, gnu-global

According to the GNU Global [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Plug_002din)

```
# Installation of GLOBAL
# It assumed that ctags command is installed in '/usr/local/bin'.

$ ./configure --with-universal-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I need to install `GNU Global` with the flag `--with-universal-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags` for support for universal-ctags.

Normal installation of `GNU Global` is done using (according to this [source](http://brewformulas.org/Global))

```
# normal installation
brew install global
```

and since brew formulas are ruby scripts of the form (according to [brew](https://brew.sh/))

```
#Example with Wget
class Wget < Formula
  homepage "https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/"
  url "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz"
  sha256 "52126be8cf1bddd7536886e74c053ad7d0ed2aa89b4b630f76785bac21695fcd"

  def install
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install"
  end
end
```

should I just do

```
# It assumed that ctags command is installed in '/usr/local/bin'.
brew install global --with-universal-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
```

to install global with universal-ctags support?

Note: The normal installation of global seems to have `exuberant-ctags` as a dependency

Comment: Relevant PR : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/8309